# Question on "pocket" universes

Tags: vacuum, cosmological-inflation

I recently heard about the possibility of the creation of a "baby" universe or "pocket" universe from our space time,the theory says that concentrating enough mass into a tiny volume of space (like in black holes) a pocket of false vacuum would form e perhaps it'll continue to expand following it's own inflation period and go on forever completly disconnected from our space time without influencing it any way. Now my question is : supposing that we live in a metastable vacuum  we know that  true vacuum bubble could form via quantum tunnelling and begin to expand into our space time where these false vacuum bubble (or pocket/baby universe) are supposed to go and expand ?

Comment: The short and snarky answer is that it depends on your model.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer eternal inflation ? i think it's related in this article http://www.casavaria.com/sentido/science/2006/06-0802-new-universe.htm